# Yammer Embed Code for Multi Topic Feed (SharePoint Online)

Tags: embed, yammer, sharepoint-online

Is is possible to add more than one topic ID to the Yammer embed code. If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported. You can specify only one feed or topic ID, as shown in the configurator: https://www.yammer.com/widget/configure

Comment: Too bad. Thanks for taking the time to answer.